# Add controls dynamically to an HTML table using Razor

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to assign a select to a string variable. Using:

`var h1 = '<td>@Html.DropDownList("idControlClass", new SelectList(Model.FooList), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</td>';`

The outcome is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" since the snippet of code results in a string with line breaks after the closing option tags.

Is there a way of assigning a the select generated from the code above to a variable without line breaks? Or some other way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you want to populate this dropdown dynamically?

Comment: Kinda, basically i want to add the same select control (generated using Razor) to a table row on a button click. Meaning when the user clicks a button, a new row with the same dropdown (the select mentioned above) is added to a html table dynamically using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing `SelectList` but it expecting `List<SelectListItem>`

try this

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> lstControlClass = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in Model.FooList)
    {
        lstControlClass.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Id , Value = item.Name  })
    }
}
var h1 = '<td>@Html.DropDownList("idControlClass", lstControlClass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</td>';
```

Or You need to set key where's is Text and Value

```
var h1 = '<td>@Html.DropDownList("idControlClass", new SelectList(Model.FooList, "Id","Name"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</td>';
```